# php echo except if empty, how to hide when multiple if statements?

Tags: php

I have multiple if statements for a header display. If the field is empty how do I hide the header? I know how to do simpler !empty but not for this.

To clarify...

There will always be a "listed" variable but not always a "broker" variable. When the "broker" variable is empty, I do not want a header to display. So it's got to check "broker" and if empty return nothing even when there is a "listed" variable. If "broker" is not empty then it must return a specific header based on which "listed" it is.

```
<?php global $post; $listed = get_post_meta($post->ID,'listed',true);
if( $listed == 'Sold' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Sold By</div><li> [broker] '; }
if( $listed == 'For Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Contact Information </div><li> [broker]'; }
if( $listed == 'Not For Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Last Active Agent </div><li> [broker]'; }
if( $listed == 'Contingent or Pending Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">If interested, contact agent for current status. </div><li> [broker]'; }
if( $listed == 'Demolished' ) { echo '<li> '; }
?>
```

Comment: which field you want to check and hide the header?

Comment: The custom field name is "listed". Based on what that field says "Sold" "For Sale" etc depends on the custom message. But if "Listed" doesn't have anything in it, I don't want it to display anything.

Comment: Wait, that's wrong. If the custom field "broker" is empty then I do not want the custom message based on the custom field "listed" to display.

Comment: `if(!empty($broker))` maybe?

Comment: no, tried that and didn't work

Comment: I would change all of this to a switch case statement and default would do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $post; $listed = get_post_meta($post->ID,'listed',true);
if(isset($listed)&&$listed!=""){
    if( $listed == 'Sold' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Sold By</div><li> [broker] '; }
    else if( $listed == 'For Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Contact Information </div><li> [broker]'; }
    else if( $listed == 'Not For Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Last Active Agent </div><li> [broker]'; }
    else if( $listed == 'Contingent or Pending Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">If interested, contact agent for current status. </div><li> [broker]'; }
    else if( $listed == 'Demolished' ) { echo '<li> '; }
    else{
        //Default case i.e. do nothing
        //Nothing here to display
    }
}
else{
    //Default case i.e. do nothing
    //Nothig here
}
```

You dont have default case. See above code. You are just using if so there is no default case defined except those conditions.
You can also do using `switch ...case` statement for default condition.

```
if(condition){
   //do something
}
else if(condition){
   //do something
}
else if(condition){
   //do something
}
else{
   //this is default case if your condition does not true with any of the above if conditions
   //Here in your case will not be anything i.e. dont echo anything
}
```

Comment: Still displaying the header display if "broker" is empty. I also tried else if empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just checking the variable?

```
<?php
global $post;
$listed = get_post_meta($post->ID,'listed',true);

if(isset($broker) AND $broker AND $listed)
{
    if( $listed == 'Sold' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Sold By</div><li> [broker] '; }
    if( $listed == 'For Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Contact Information </div><li> [broker]'; }
    if( $listed == 'Not For Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Last Active Agent </div><li> [broker]'; }
    if( $listed == 'Contingent or Pending Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">If interested, contact agent for current status. </div><li> [broker]'; }
    if( $listed == 'Demolished' ) { echo '<li> '; }
}
else
{
    // Echo nothing
    echo "";
}
```

Comment: As in is it empty? Yes, no text is in the broker field.

Comment: What about `if($listed AND $broker)`? I am only aware of your `$listed` variable.

Comment: There will always be a "listed" variable but not always a "broker" variable. When the "broker" variable is empty, I do not want a header to display. So it's got to check "broker" and if empty return nothing. If "broker" is not empty then it must return a specific header based on which "listed" it is.

Comment: I'm trying if ($listed AND $broker), still no go.

Comment: Try `if(isset($broker) AND $broker AND $listed)`. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed it.

```
<?php 
$listed = get_post_meta($post->ID,'listed',true);

$broker = get_post_meta($post->ID,'broker',true);

if( $listed && $broker ){

if( $listed == 'Sold' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Sold By</div><li> [broker]    [officephone]   </li>'; }
if( $listed == 'For Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Contact Information </div><li> [broker]    [officephone]   </li>'; }
if( $listed == 'Not For Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">Last Active Agent </div><li> [broker]    [officephone]   </li>'; }
if( $listed == 'Contingent or Pending Sale' ) { echo ' <div class="more-information">If interested, contact agent for current status. </div><li> [broker]    [officephone]   </li>'; }
if( $listed == 'Demolished' ) { echo ' '; } 
} ?>
```

Comment: This is the same as what myself and http://stackoverflow.com/users/7259671/webdev did.